# RecyclerView: add footer with item decoration?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is that possible to add footer with item decoration, and not using adapter? Since I'm working with a very complex adapter with already lot of different viewholder types, I'd like to add an identical footer seamlessly to every list in my app.

Comment: are you using adapter with listView or gridview?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, but as stated in the title, I'm using a recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

As far as i can tell, this inst't best practice.

Here's description from RecyclerView.ItemDecoration class:

```
 /**
 * An ItemDecoration allows the application to add a special drawing and layout offset
 * to specific item views from the adapter's data set. This can be useful for drawing dividers
 * between items, highlights, visual grouping boundaries and more.
```

However You can set specific behaviour when implementing your own divider based on adapter viewtype divider has to deal with. Here's an example code i used in one online course:

```
public class Divider extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private Drawable mDivider;
private int mOrientation;

public Divider(Context context, int orientation) {
    mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.divider);
    if (orientation != LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("This Item Decoration can be used only with a RecyclerView that uses a LinearLayoutManager with vertical orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        drawHorizontalDivider(c, parent, state);
    }
}

private void drawHorizontalDivider(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left, top, right, bottom;
    left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();
    int count = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    //here we check the itemViewType we deal with, you can implement your own behaviour for Footer type.
    // In this example i draw a drawable below every item that IS NOT Footer, as i defined Footer as a button in view
        if (Adapter.FOOTER != parent.getAdapter().getItemViewType(i)) {
            View current = parent.getChildAt(i);
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) current.getLayoutParams();
            top = current.getTop() - params.topMargin;
            bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
            mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
            mDivider.draw(c);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    }
}
```

Or you can use a library called [Flexible Divider](https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-FlexibleDivider) that allows for using a custom drawable or resource to be set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anton. You're right about not being the best practice since the item decorator might have different purpose, so probably I might fallback to the old and cleaner adapter with different view types.